# Slow parsing of 23 kB XML file with more than half second

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to build objects based on xmlreader:

```
        List<Element> units = new List<Element>();

        string path = "D:\\Item\\Unit.xml";

        XElement xelement = XElement.Load(path);
        IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xelement.Elements();

        foreach (var c in elements)
        {
            Element stb = new Element();
            stb.Name = c.Element("Name").Value;
            stb.Picture = c.Element("Picture").Value;
            //and next 30 options included try / catch for int.Parse
         }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
<row id="1">
    <Name>Freighter</Name>
    <Picture>Item\Freighter.gif</Picture>
    ... and 30 next rows with data for each "unit"
</row>
    ... and 30 next units...
<rows>
```

As I told, XML is 23kB file with 30 rows per each unit, with total 30 units in file. Not sure why this code is so slow: it took 670 miliseconds (i3 processor).
The slowest part is obiect fillig, but not sure how to improve it.

The complete code looks exactly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace element_reader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CustomStopwatch sw = new CustomStopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            List<Element> ships = new List<Element>();

            string path = "D:\\Ship_test.xml";

            XElement xelement = XElement.Load(path);
            IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xelement.Elements();

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Stopwatch elapsed: {0}, StartAt: {1}, EndAt: {2}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, sw.StartAt.Value, sw.EndAt.Value);
            sw.Start();

            foreach (var c in elements)
            {
                Element stb = new Element();
                stb.Name = c.Element("Name").Value;
                stb.Picture = c.Element("Picture").Value;

                try
                {
                    stb.Prt = int.Parse(c.Element("PRT").Value);
                }
                catch
                { stb.Prt = 0; }

                try
                {
                    stb.Lrt = int.Parse(c.Element("LRT").Value);
                }
                catch
                { stb.Lrt = 0; }

                stb.Special = c.Element("Special").Value;

                try
                {
                    stb.Wep = int.Parse(c.Element("Wep").Value);
                }
                catch
                { stb.Wep = 0; }

                try
                {
                    stb.Con = int.Parse(c.Element("Con").Value);
                }
                catch
                { stb.Con = 0; }

                try
                {
                    stb.Ene = int.Parse(c.Element("Ene").Value);
                }
                catch
                { stb.Ene = 0; }

                try
                {
                    stb.Ele = int.Parse(c.Element("Ele").Value);
                }
                catch
                { stb.Ele = 0; }

                try
                {
                    stb.Prp = int.Parse(c.Element("Prp").Value);
                }
                catch
                { stb.Prp = 0; }

                try
                {
                    stb.Bio = int.Parse(c.Element("Bio").Value);
                }
                catch
                { stb.Bio = 0; }


                try
                {
                    stb.Mass = int.Parse(c.Element("Mass").Value);
                }
                catch
                { stb.Mass = 0; }


                try
                {
                    stb.Iro = int.Parse(c.Element("Iro").Value);
                }
                catch
                { stb.Iro = 0; }

                try
                {
                    stb.Bor = int.Parse(c.Element("Bor").Value);
                }
                catch
                { stb.Bor = 0; }

                try
                {
                    stb.Ger = int.Parse(c.Element("Ger").Value);
                }
                catch
                { stb.Ger = 0; }

                try
                {
                    stb.Res = int.Parse(c.Element("Res").Value);
                }
                catch
                { stb.Res = 0; }


                ships.Add(stb);
            }

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Stopwatch elapsed: {0}, StartAt: {1}, EndAt: {2}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, sw.StartAt.Value, sw.EndAt.Value);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class Element
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Picture;

        public int Prt;
        public int Lrt;

        public string Special;

        public int Con;
        public int Wep;
        public int Ene;
        public int Ele;
        public int Prp;
        public int Bio;

        public int Mass;

        public int Iro;
        public int Bor;
        public int Ger;
        public int Res;
    }

    public class CustomStopwatch : Stopwatch
    {

        public DateTime? StartAt { get; private set; }
        public DateTime? EndAt { get; private set; }


        public void Start()
        {
            StartAt = DateTime.Now;

            base.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            EndAt = DateTime.Now;

            base.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

When the part of XML looks exactly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
<row id="1">
    <Name>Small Freighter</Name>
    <Picture>Item\Ship\Ship01_1.gif</Picture>
    <Description></Description>
    <PRT></PRT>
    <LRT></LRT>
    <Special></Special>

    <Ene>0</Ene>
    <Wep>0</Wep>
    <Prp>0</Prp>
    <Con>0</Con>
    <Ele>0</Ele>
    <Bio>0</Bio>

    <Slot1>-150, 0, Engine, 1, 1, 1</Slot1>
    <Slot2>-50, 0, Cargo, 70, 1, 1</Slot2>
    <Slot3>50, 0, DEF, 1, 1, 1</Slot3>
    <Slot4>150, 0, SEM, 1, 1, 1</Slot4>

    <Mass>25</Mass>

    <Res>20</Res>
    <Iro>12</Iro>
    <Res>0</Res>
    <Ger>17</Ger>

    <Fuel>130</Fuel>
    <Cargo>70</Cargo>
    <HPD_arm>25</HPD_arm>
    <Initiative>0</Initiative>
</row>
</rows>
```

Result is 70ms for 1kB file !!!
If I have 20 files to load with 20-30 rows each this method is completely useless.
Please notice that I do not use all data located in file.

Comment: A lot of factors here. Release or Debug mode, what kind of HDD ?

Comment: Can you show all of the code that processes the XML?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide full `xml` file content, so I just only can suggest you one thing.
Use `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse`. I bet your code throws hundreds of exceptions which are very CPU expensive.

Comment: Yeah, exception throwing is very slow. `TryParse` much more better.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the code should look like this :

```
            List<Element> elements = xelement.Descendants("TagName").Select(x => new Element() {
                Name = (string)x.Element("Name"),
                Picture = (string)x.Element("Picture")
            }).ToList();
```

Here is the comparison of the times
Time 1 = '11.0082', Time 2 = '4.0032'

Here is code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Element newElement = new Element() {
                Name = "John",
                Picture = "Dorian Grey",
                Data1 = "1",
                Data2 = "1",
                Data3 = "1",
                Data4 = "1",
                Data5 = "1",
                Data6 = "1",
                Data7 = "1",
                Data8 = "1",
                Data9 = "1",
                Data10 = "1",
                Data11 = "1",
                Data12 = "1",
                Data13 = "1",
                Data14 = "1",
                Data15 = "1",
                Data16 = "1",
                Data17 = "1",
                Data18 = "1",
                Data19 = "1",
                Data20 = "1",
                Data21 = "1",
                Data22 = "1",
                Data23 = "1",
                Data24 = "1",
                Data25 = "1",
                Data26 = "1",
                Data27 = "1",
                Data28 = "1",
                Data29 = "1",
                Data30 = "1"
            };
            Root root = new Root();

            for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
            {
                root.elements.Add(newElement);
            }
            XmlWriterSettings setting = new XmlWriterSettings();
            setting.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, setting);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, root);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            DateTime start1 = DateTime.Now;

            List<Element> units = new List<Element>();
            List<XElement> elements = doc.Root.Elements().ToList();
            foreach (var c in elements)
            {
                Element stb = new Element();
                stb.Name = c.Element("Name").Value;
                stb.Picture = c.Element("Picture").Value;
                stb.Data1 = c.Element("Data1").Value;
                stb.Data2 = c.Element("Data2").Value;
                stb.Data3 = c.Element("Data3").Value;
                stb.Data4 = c.Element("Data4").Value;
                stb.Data5 = c.Element("Data5").Value;
                stb.Data6 = c.Element("Data6").Value;
                stb.Data7 = c.Element("Data7").Value;
                stb.Data8 = c.Element("Data8").Value;
                stb.Data9 = c.Element("Data9").Value;
                stb.Data10 = c.Element("Data10").Value;
                stb.Data11 = c.Element("Data11").Value;
                stb.Data12 = c.Element("Data12").Value;
                stb.Data13 = c.Element("Data13").Value;
                stb.Data14 = c.Element("Data14").Value;
                stb.Data15 = c.Element("Data15").Value;
                stb.Data16 = c.Element("Data16").Value;
                stb.Data17 = c.Element("Data17").Value;
                stb.Data18 = c.Element("Data18").Value;
                stb.Data19 = c.Element("Data19").Value;
                stb.Data20 = c.Element("Data20").Value;
                stb.Data21 = c.Element("Data21").Value;
                stb.Data22 = c.Element("Data22").Value;
                stb.Data23 = c.Element("Data23").Value;
                stb.Data24 = c.Element("Data24").Value;
                stb.Data25 = c.Element("Data25").Value;
                stb.Data26 = c.Element("Data26").Value;
                stb.Data27 = c.Element("Data27").Value;
                stb.Data28 = c.Element("Data28").Value;
                stb.Data29 = c.Element("Data29").Value;
                stb.Data30 = c.Element("Data30").Value;
                units.Add(stb);
            }
            DateTime end1 = DateTime.Now;

            DateTime start2 = DateTime.Now;
            List<Element> elements2 = doc.Descendants("elements").Select(x => new Element()
            {
                Name = (string)x.Element("Name"),
                Picture = (string)x.Element("Picture"),
                Data1 = (string)x.Element("Data1"),
                Data2 = (string)x.Element("Data2"),
                Data3 = (string)x.Element("Data3"),
                Data4 = (string)x.Element("Data4"),
                Data5 = (string)x.Element("Data5"),
                Data6 = (string)x.Element("Data6"),
                Data7 = (string)x.Element("Data7"),
                Data8 = (string)x.Element("Data8"),
                Data9 = (string)x.Element("Data9"),
                Data10 = (string)x.Element("Data10"),
                Data11 = (string)x.Element("Data11"),
                Data12 = (string)x.Element("Data12"),
                Data13 = (string)x.Element("Data13"),
                Data14 = (string)x.Element("Data14"),
                Data15 = (string)x.Element("Data15"),
                Data16 = (string)x.Element("Data16"),
                Data17 = (string)x.Element("Data17"),
                Data18 = (string)x.Element("Data18"),
                Data19 = (string)x.Element("Data19"),
                Data20 = (string)x.Element("Data20"),
                Data21 = (string)x.Element("Data21"),
                Data22 = (string)x.Element("Data22"),
                Data23 = (string)x.Element("Data23"),
                Data24 = (string)x.Element("Data24"),
                Data25 = (string)x.Element("Data25"),
                Data26 = (string)x.Element("Data26"),
                Data27 = (string)x.Element("Data27"),
                Data28 = (string)x.Element("Data28"),
                Data29 = (string)x.Element("Data29"),
                Data30 = (string)x.Element("Data30"),

            }).ToList();
            DateTime end2 = DateTime.Now;

            string results = string.Format("Time 1 = '{0}', Time 2 = '{1}'", (end1 - start1).TotalMilliseconds, (end2 - start2).TotalMilliseconds); 

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public List<Element> elements = new List<Element>();
    }

    public class Element
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Picture { get; set; }
        public string Data1 { get; set; }
        public string Data2 { get; set; }
        public string Data3 { get; set; }
        public string Data4 { get; set; }
        public string Data5 { get; set; }
        public string Data6 { get; set; }
        public string Data7 { get; set; }
        public string Data8 { get; set; }
        public string Data9 { get; set; }
        public string Data10 { get; set; }
        public string Data11 { get; set; }
        public string Data12 { get; set; }
        public string Data13 { get; set; }
        public string Data14 { get; set; }
        public string Data15 { get; set; }
        public string Data16 { get; set; }
        public string Data17 { get; set; }
        public string Data18 { get; set; }
        public string Data19 { get; set; }
        public string Data20 { get; set; }
        public string Data21 { get; set; }
        public string Data22 { get; set; }
        public string Data23 { get; set; }
        public string Data24 { get; set; }
        public string Data25 { get; set; }
        public string Data26 { get; set; }
        public string Data27 { get; set; }
        public string Data28 { get; set; }
        public string Data29 { get; set; }
        public string Data30 { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why SHOULD he use Linq? Linq is not faster, which is what he wants.

Comment: Have you ever compared the times?

Comment: @PoulBak this is not normal Linq, this is ["Linq to XML"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml). This generates a query that will navigate the xml structure, not just blindly enumerate like normal linq would do. The thing you are thinking of is "Linq to Objects" which would be slower.

Comment: There is a small mistake. The first method iterates the XML twice because you call `ToList` before looping over it. If you get rid of the `ToList` you should see better times for the first method.

Comment: You need the ToList() if you have List<XElement>.  You would need to use var if you removed the ToList().  Then difference is less than 1 millisecond.

Comment: I also didn't include the Load() in the times.  The slow time may be due to the read of the file.

Comment: You don't really need a List honestly so you could loop over the call to `Elements` directly and save a few ms.